# GPath testing for decimal value

Tags: groovy, gpath

Using Rest Assured in Java to test some APIs. Trying to use GPath to return a value.

Why does this work?

```
int i = response.path("Result.find{it.Amount>293.50 && it.Amount<293.52 && it.CreatedDate=='10/26/2018'}.Id");
```

But this doesn't?

```
int i = response.path("Result.find{it.Amount==293.51 && it.CreatedDate=='10/26/2018'}.Id");
```

Does GPath have some weird thing about decimal values?  I'm new to GPath and have tried researching but can't find anything conclusive.

Comment: do you have any error? or what does it mean `doesn't work` ?

Comment: I'm running it in Java.  The error is just thrown on that particular line.  If I use the greater than and less than operators that little 'query' returns the integer value that I'm expecting.  If I use the '==' operator, when Java hits that line it just crashes.  The '==' operator doesn't work like I thought it would.  No integer value is returned.

Answer (score 1):

An exceptionally bright co-worker found the answer for me.  Posting here to help those of you trying to figure it out.

In order to test double values it should read:

```
int i = response.path("Result.find{it.Amount.toDouble()==293.51 && it.CreatedDate=='10/26/2018'}.Id");
```